# Estimate decile groups with NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate decile groups for two columns. First column is for 2015 and second is for 2016. Each of this contain NA values. In order to do that I wrote function:

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n){
                  qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n))
                  out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))
                  return(out)
                }
```

This function work well and now I want to estimate decile groups by each separate columns

```
 FACT_SALES_PD<-mutate(FACT_SALES_P,
                    deciles_2015=qgroup(gross_i.2015, 10,na.rm=TRUE),
                    deciles_2016=qgroup(gross_i.2016, 10,na.rm=TRUE))
```

But now I face with problem because this two column contain NA values. This is error which I recive:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `deciles_2015`.
i `deciles_2015 = qgroup(gross_i.2015, 10, na.rm = TRUE)`.
x unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can me help somebody how to solve this problem and estimate deciles groups without cleaning NA values ?

Comment: I think you should add the `na.rm=TRUE` option to the `quantile` function in your definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:You could set the default value to TRUE:

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n, na.rm=TRUE){
                  qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n), na.rm)  # will pick up the value from the default setting
                  out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))
                  return(out)
                }
```

Option 2: You could try adding an ellipsis argument. It can accept optional named arguments that can be extracted by interior functions.

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n, ...){
                      qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n), ...)
                      out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))
                      return(out)
                    }
```

It then becomes the "responsibility" of the interior function to determine if the named argument has any meaning. This second method has the advantage that you can use any of the named arguments for quantile. You could also pass in arguments to other functions at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You use an extra argument in your home-made function : na.rm. So R doesn't understand what he's supposed to do with this information.

You can use dplyr though to do grouped Quantiles. Check-out the functions **group_by** and **summarize** and their applications on quantiles().

Cheers

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow. Thanks for you support.